# xattr write delimiter

Tags: macos, command-line

I am trying to write OM tags using xattr.

```
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags tag1 a.rtf
```

This works fine for one tag, but how do I add two or more? I have tried various combinations of quotes, commas, \, etc. without success so far.

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OM tags (com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags) as well as user defined tags (com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags) are stored in an extended attribute and its value is a binary property list that contains a single array of strings.

Example with the tag *user* (xxd'd and converted to a xml with plutil):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>user</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Simply using `xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags tag1 file` won't create a properly defined OMUser or (Apple) User tag.

I recommend to use an "add tag" Python script like this [one](http://www.codegist.net/snippet/python/tagpy_ishahid_python).

---

*kMDItemOMUserTags* seems to be outdated (or at least ["difficult" to use](https://macademic.org/2013/10/24/os-x-mavericks-and-openmeta-tags-the-first-impression/)) in macOS and are sometimes/often replaced with the *_kMDItemUserTags* even in OpenMeta apps.